# program crashes due to file format

Tags: c, crash

i was trying this problem from usaco. when i use txt file while using file the program is working fine. but when for the submission requirement i change the format to beads.in and beads.out the program crashes. what;s the problem?
here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main () {
    FILE *fin  = fopen ("beads.in", "r");
    FILE *fout = fopen ("beads.out", "w");
    int n;
    char str[400];
    char now,rev_now;
    int pos,forward,reverse,sum,max=0,i,j,k;
    fscanf(fin,"%d\n%s",&n,str);
    n--;
    for(pos=0;pos<=n;pos++){
        now=str[pos];
        if(pos==0)k=n;
        else k=pos-1;
        rev_now=str[k];
        forward=2;
        int flag1=0,flag2=0,reverse=2;

        for(i=pos,j=k;;){
            if(i==n)i=-1;
            if((str[i+1]==now||str[i+1]=='w')&&flag1==0){
                i++;
                forward++;
            }
            else{
                flag1=1;
            }
            if(j==0)j=n+1;
            if((str[j-1]==rev_now||str[j-1]=='w')&&flag2==0){
                j++;
                reverse++;
            }
            else{
                flag2=1;
            }
            if(flag1==1 && flag2==1)break;
        }
        sum=forward+reverse;
        if(max<sum){max=sum;}
    }
    fprintf(fout,"%d\n",max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use _gdb_ or some other debugger to look at where exactly its crashing and why.

Comment: Maybe you can try `fopen ("beads.in", "rb");` and `fopen ("beads.out", "wb");`.

Comment: Can you give sample beads.in content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention that it works with a text file. I'm guessing that `beads.in` is not a text file, but rather a binary file. If that is the case, then @KVD's suggestion above to use: `fopen ("beads.in", "rb");` and `fopen ("beads.out", "wb");` should work. The reason the program would crash with binary input data is because you are asking `fscanf` to copy data into your `str` buffer until it encounters a newline character. More than likely, the `beads.in` file has more than 400 characters which will cause a buffer overflow and start overwriting the program stack.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure `beads.in` and `beads.out` are created already..

According to man page

```
 r      Open  text  file  for  reading.  The stream is positioned at the
        beginning of the file.

 w      Truncate  file  to  zero length or create text file for writing.
        The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.
```

May be `beads.in` is not created in prior to fopen. It's better if you check the status of the `fopen`, use `perror`.